# Можно ли как-то перенести настройку CornerRadius в сам экспандер?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

В Wpf шаблон контрола Expander состоит из Border'а и вложенных в этот бордер других контроллов. У этого бордера есть свойство CornerRadius="3". То есть оно задается напрямую в шаблоне и задать его при добавлении к Xaml самого экспандера нельзя.

Есть в шаблоне у этого бордера и другие свойства, например, BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}". А у, соответственно, экспандера Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" И таким образом, когда мы задаем BorderThickness для экспандера, это значение "пробрасывается" в BorderThickness бордера.

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        CornerRadius="0" 
...
```

Можно ли как-то сделать такую же вещь для CornerRadius или это доступно только для свойств, которые присутствуют у обоих контролов?

Comment: Можно использовать собственное свойство (AttachedProperty) [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232502/template-binding-with-attached-properties)

Comment: Если у верхнего объекта нету определенного свойства, то вы не сможете его использовать при создание (прим `<Expander CornerRadius="3" />`, как вы и говорите, `CornerRadius` у `Expander`'a нет, а значит и задать его мы не можем). Я недавно делал окно, в котором есть ряд новых элементов и я хотел доступ к этим элементам вынести за пределы стиля, в удобные свойства, и вот что я сделал: Создал класс, унаследовал его от `Window`, сделал там нужные мне `DependencyProperty` (в студии `propdp` - TAB) и все, дальше в шаблоне все привязал на них. В разметке было `<ctrl:MyCustomWindow MyProp="..">`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , а есть это окно где-нибудь в открытом доступе, на гитхабе например?

Comment: А какая тут связь и разница? Просто тот, кто его будет использовать должен знать, что у данного окна есть доп свойства для взаимодействия со стилем. А если это "окно" уже используется, то ему не горячо не холодно будет, при сборке проект поведет себя также, как и стандартный. Ну либо делайте как вам сказали выше, AP, тоже весьма не плохой вариант, правда я ненавижу их громоздкость (`<Control local:SomeClass.SomeProperty="value">` или `<local:CustomControl SomeProperty = "value">`) и захламление подсказок у студии)